# Error at importing dll file to an UWP project using c#

Tags: c#, dll, uwp, dispatcher

I'm working on UWP Project and, i want to add a reference it shows me a message error. I need that reference for using Dispatcher class and i dont find it on references path.

Any solutions ?

[Message Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClkgL.png)

Or if I install the dll file from NuGet Packages it throws me this warning:

> Warning  NU1701  Package 'WindowsBase 4.6.1055' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   'UAP,Version=v10.0.17763'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal to have this error, since the reference you want to add is already integrated in **UWP projects** at the reference level you will find your dispatcher, you could use the code below to use dispatcher  .

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
       // do some staff
});
```